# I Ejaculated long time ago and i didn't know that my prayers won't be accepted till GHUSL

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, muslim-practices

**Hello everyone, please help me! I Ejaculated long time ago and i didn't know that my prayers won't be accepted till GHUSL till i saw some posts about it. should i re-offer all the prayers i missed before (i prayed all of them) after doing ghusl or i can just continue? because i'm 14 years old and i'm still learning.. i didn't know... also i ejaculated a really long time ago, like i prayed more than 50 sallat and i didn't do ghusl or anything.
please help me in this hard situation.**

Comment: make tawba and continue praying now that you know. whats important is you don't repeat the same mistake again and as you didn't know before, it dosen't matter. what done in ignorance is forgiven, insha Allah.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! may allah bless you.

Comment: [This](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/344401/performing-many-prayers-with-invalid-ablution) should help. This ruling is not only logical and correct but also it can remove your hardship.

Comment: AlexQurari, the name seems similar, are you a stickman YouTuber? :O I used to watch them as a kid.

Answer (score 0):

I try to look your problem in google and i found articles that say there is 2 opinion among scholar, the first opinion is you must re offer your sallat again, and the second opinion is you don't need to re offer your salat again, that articles say the strongest opinion is the second opinion, sorry for my bad english
This is the article that i look, its Indonesian article but you can translate it using auto translate feature or translate it manually by google translate : https://konsultasisyariah.com/20993-tidak-mandi-junub-tahunan-karena-tidak-tahu.html

Im really sorry if the article is indonesian, my english is bad so i cant search your question in google by english

Answer (score 0):

Since you were unaware of the rule it may be forgiven.

However, salah is the 2nd most important pillar of Islam, and if you weren't forgiven, it may be the difference between jannah and jahanam for you, something you shouldn't risk.

Many other people have made up hundreds of salah and praying 1 extra a day would barely take 2 months to re-offer. In the long term, repeating is the more logical choice.